# MAUI: The app is working fine in debug mode and craches with the APK published or in relese mode

Tags: maui

My app is working fine in debug mode and no issues are with the UI or functionalities. But when I create the APK file, the UI color is changing and the app is breaking when tapping on a button. So I check in release mode and found the same issue.

**Debug Mode Screenshot:**

[image]

**Release Mode Screenshot:**

[image]

In release mode the app icon is also not visible on the UI. Also the launcher icon and launching screen are also breaking.

I am facing these issue after updating to .net 8 from .net 7. When the project is on .net 7 there was no such issue. Do I need to add anything else for the proper working of the app in .net 8?

**VS Version:** Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview Version 17.10.0 Preview 2.0

I tried the solutions on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75826492/why-is-my-maui-app-crashing-in-release-mode-but-works-fine-in-debug-mode) and no luck.

Comment: It seems your image files are missed, did you try to publish or release a new maui project template?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Image files are there in project and working fine in debug mode.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I put the codes on a newly created .net 8 project and facing no issues. The issue is only on the converted .net 8 project from .net 7

Comment: Yes, I just updated my VS to  Preview Version 17.10.0 Preview 2.0 and tried published and released the new project. There is no problem.

Comment: So the problem seems to be your project. Could you please provide a smallest sample that can reproduce your problem?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT For reproducing and sharing I removed all the pages and keeps the login page only , but at that time app has no issue in release mode. So I need to share the entire project to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I saw it, if you keep two or three page can this be reproduced? And did this appear on all devices?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257169/discussion-between-matthew-pans-and-liyun-zhang-msft).

Answer (score 0):

Could be a xaml compiler optimization issue. Basically the compiler optimizes the xaml code in release mode to lower the package size or improve the overall performance of the app.

I would recommend adding

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Skip)]
```

on the .xaml.cs files on the pages that don't render correctly and see if that makes a difference.

You can also enable the optimizations for debug mode in project properties>build so you'll see the same rendering of the page in debug mode if this is the problem.

[image]

Comment: This is not a xaml compiler optimization issue. I tried adding `XamlCompilationOptions.Skip` on the pages and same issue and there is no issue when I enable the optimizations for debug mode in project properties.

Comment: I am able to recreate the issue. Here is the link of the demo project, could you please check. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Inux4Qg82Md0aL1i989QGV252L-dzJrl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The launcher icon and launching screen are also breaking.

Comment: I have tested and the debug mode has the same result as release mode.And the spalsh screen background color is white but the icon is correct. @MatthewPans

Comment: The white color is setted by you in the csproj. And I also publish it as apk and install it. There is no problem. @MatthewPans

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT What is the background color of the login page in release mode? Is it white or yellow? The background color of the launching screen I set as white, but I am getting blue in release mode and the launcher icon is half broken in release mode. Please check this video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y1K5iEod4m_lJURF_QrTapv3laly54Yq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In the release mode, it is still white and the splash icon showed correctly. I tested it on redmi with android 14. It worked correctly in debug, release and packaged apk. @MatthewPans

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT What is your visual studio version? Any other settings added on the project properties other than disabling AOT?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Did you check the video I shared? I am getting blue launching screen, white login page and broken launcher icon.

Comment: Did you create the APK using Command line?

Comment: Same for me, seems like it works for both debug and release modes

Comment: I just downloaded the project you provided and then created the apk with the command line directly. I also used Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview Version 17.10.0 Preview 2.0. @MatthewPans

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I am also trying to create the apk using command line. I used the below comamnd: `dotnet publish -f net8.0-android -c Release -p:AndroidKeyStore=true -p:AndroidSigningKeyStore=listpm.pagematics.com.keystore -p:AndroidSigningKeyAlias=listpm.pagematics.com -p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=password -p:AndroidSigningStorePass=password` but I am getting below error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVOjd.png

Comment: I have a keystore file already and I am trying to use that here. When I use that, it says keystore file not found.

Comment: Did you try to [Find your keystore's signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-cli?view=net-maui-8.0)? In addition, you can try to use `dotnet build -c Release -f net8.0-android /p:AndroidPackageFormats=apk --no-restore` to publish it. @MatthewPans

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I did like this and it is success, but where I can see the APK file, under which folder. https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBPvx.png

Comment: In the `bin\Release\net8.0-android\publish` floder. @MatthewPans

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I tried the APK on this folder and same issue with that. I tried with the signed APk and the other one is not installable. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed1D1.png

Comment: But I downloaded the project you provided and didn't meet the issue. @MatthewPans

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Let me try again, I don't know what is happening.

Comment: Did you try it on different devices or emulators? @MatthewPans

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I tried on a different device and same issue.

Comment: Sorry for I have no idea about this. I can't reproduce it. @MatthewPans